# Installing nodejs on Debian 6

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, debian

Lots of (old?) posts suggest that if one wants to install node.js on Debian 6 (in my case this is an Amazon EC2 t1.micro instance I am experimenting with), then one needs to compile your own given the fact that Debian packages significantly lag the frenzied pace of node.js development.

The [node.js website](http://nodejs.org/) lists v0.10.17 as the current stable release.   The current [nodejs package information](http://packages.debian.org/sid/nodejs) nicely also lists the same (0.10.17~dfsg1-2) which sounds great right?  Don't have to do a make after all!

Problem is that this request:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Produces these results:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nodejs
```

So my question is this: am I seeing what it looks like when a package is PLANNED but not yet created, or is there maybe some apt-get issue going on here that my installation just doesn't see the nodejs package and therefore cannot install it?  Am I stuck with having to do a make? (which btw,  blew up on me when I tried it).

Comment: See the instructions given [here](http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/read/41-install-node-js-on-debian-wheezy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the steps you took to compile from source. This is what I used and It worked well on multiple servers:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential

sudo apt-get install wget

wget (link to node.js source -> found on nodejs.org/download/)

tar xvf node(press tab to auto load the version you're on)

pushd node(again, use tab)

./configure

make 

sudo make install
```

TO TEST:

```
node

0.1 + 0.2
```

You should receive a response. All set.

Comment: Thanks for these instructions; I will give them a try since I did NOT follow these (I followed this: https://sekati.com/etc/install-nodejs-on-debian-squeeze).  But do you know why http://packages.debian.org/sid/nodejs shows a package for 0.10.17?

Comment: I know from looking on nodejs.org that v0.10.17 is their most current version. I've heard normal repositories have a difficult time keeping up with the most current version of node since it is evolving so fast. This is why I choose to compile from source for my projects. Best of luck trying the instructions!

Comment: Your instructions went very smoothly.  The previous link I shared from sekati.com contains instructions to clone from git, and I wonder if something went wrong in that step.  The error messages scrolling past during the make used the words "dying badly".

Comment: One thing to add for anyone else using the above instructions is to not forget that you need python as well to run the make for node.  Use sudo apt-get install python

Comment: Just used these instructions on Jessie. Thanks.